# Retrieving value of JSON variables

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, eval

I have a JSON object which is generated from my website, however I need to know how you can get a JSON variable in each value, e.g.

```
var json = '{"item":"one","item2":"two","item3":"three"}';

var js = eval('(' + json + ')');

for(var i in js)
{
    alert(i);   
}
```

This will return `item`, `item2`, `item3` but I need to get the values of each of them, `one`, `two`, `three`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use eval

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json);

for (var key in obj) {
    var value = obj[key];
    // do stuff.

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this inside your for loop:

```
alert(js[i]);
```

Comment: Ah yes, wasn't thinking properly :O